# How to align 3 different tables evenly to each other that are styled using Bootstrap?

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to align all three tables. You can see the 2nd column in the 2nd table isn't aligned with table 1 and 3. I need to fix this. I am developing in ASP.NET Core 2.0 using CSS and Bootstrap for the front-end.

I've tried to look up help on StackOverFlow already. I used this CSS to try and override the behavior.

```
.table > tbody > tr > td,
.table > tbody > tr > th, .table > tfoot > tr > td,
.table > tfoot > tr > th, .table > thead > tr > td,
.table > thead > tr > th {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="tdheader">Size</th>
            <th class="tdheader">Cost</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Sizes)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="white">@item.Type</td>
                <td class="white">$@item.Cost</td>
            </tr>

        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="tdheader">Crust</th>
            <th class="tdheader">Cost</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Crusts)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="white">@item.Type</td>
                <td class="white">$@item.Cost</td>
            </tr>

        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="tdheader">Topping</th>
            <th class="tdheader">Cost</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Toppings)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="white">@item.Type</td>
                <td class="white">$@item.Cost</td>
            </tr>

        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'll try to add an image to this question shortly.

[Picture is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhF5I.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `table-fixed` to fix the width of columns:

```
 <style>
    .table > tbody > tr > td,
    .table > tbody > tr > th, .table > tfoot > tr > td,
    .table > tfoot > tr > th, .table > thead > tr > td,
    .table > thead > tr > th {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    table {
        table-layout: fixed;
    }

    table td {
        width: 50%;
    }
</style>
```